# junit java test for function with AES encryption(javax.crypt library) not working. Android device

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, encryption, junit

I start testing my Android application with jUnit, And i test function with javax.crypto library.

I try **Cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);** function.
With simple android debbuger everything works fine, but with junit test I get an error(InvalidKeyException),I do not understand why?. Feeling so this function do not get my date. Or maybe junit do not have access for this javax.crypto library?

My full code is:

```
public void testEncryptionKey(){
    MessageDigest digest = null;
    try {

        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update("Hello".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
        keyBytes = digest.digest();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,"AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = getIV();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV()
{
    byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
    ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    byte[] ivv = ivParameterSpec.getIV();
    return ivParameterSpec;
}
```

Here is screenshot with the error:

[image: error]

Comment: what are you trying to test? the the implementation of crypto lib or *your* implementation? If the latter: use a mocking framework to replace the real crypto lib objects by easier to handle fakes.